# How to get values from xml output using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapui

How to get values from below result using PHP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <p558:registerDonorResponse xmlns:p558="http://ws.ots.labcorp.com">
          <p558:registerDonorReturn xmlns:p118="http://data.ws.ots.labcorp.com">
            <p118:clientRegistrationId>clr1</p118:clientRegistrationId>
            <p118:labcorpRegistrationNumber>100059064</p118:labcorpRegistrationNumber>
            <p118:registrationTime>2012-12-01T05:40:51.628Z</p118:registrationTime>
          </p558:registerDonorReturn>
        </p558:registerDonorResponse>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow.  You need to give more details of what you've tried, and what didn't work. "We can't able to get exact values" isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML contains namespace-prefixed tags as it's common for SOAP responses.

Have a look at following [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php#107541) from php's SimpleXML docs:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people xmlns:p="http://example.org/ns" xmlns:t="http://example.org/test">
    <p:person id="1">John Doe</p:person>
    <p:person id="2">Susie Q. Public</p:person>
</people>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$ns = $sxe->getNamespaces(true);

$child = $sxe->children($ns['p']);

foreach ($child->person as $out_ns)
{
    echo $out_ns;
}
```

In your case code accessing the properties should look like that (it's tested against your XML in so.xml file):

```
<?php
  $xml = file_get_contents('so.xml');
  $sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);

  $ns = $sxe->getNamespaces(true);

  $child =
    $sxe->children($ns['soapenv'])->
      Body->children($ns['p558'])->
      registerDonorResponse->registerDonorReturn->children($ns['p118']);

  var_dump($child);
```

Result:

```
$ php -f so.php 
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
  ["clientRegistrationId"]=>
  string(4) "clr1"
  ["labcorpRegistrationNumber"]=>
  string(9) "100059064"
  ["registrationTime"]=>
  string(24) "2012-12-01T05:40:51.628Z"
}
```

Please note however that issuing SOAP requests and parsing responses by hand is generally a bad practice, consider using [SOAP client](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) for that.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Anyway you can use PHP's [`simplexml_load_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) or the full featured [`DOMDocument class`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)